# Setting entry text box size in Tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am attempting to create a form that requires some entry options to be more than one line long.  This does not seem possible with the .Entry() function.

This issue is that I dont see anywhere in the documentation how to restrict the size of the text entry box (particularly, number of lines, or height)

To be clear, I am not trying to set the placement height, or text size, I am trying to restrict the number of lines where text can be entered (so the form is a predictable size) this is necessary because for each item I am using .place() to put them at certain pixel locations, and thus .pack() is not a viable solution for my problems either

Some reference material:

[Documentation for entry widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: _"I am trying to restrict the number of lines where text can be entered (so the form is a predictable size)"_ - what you're asking isn't clear. For one, the Entry widget only allows you to enter a single line, so setting the size is irrelevant. For the text widget, the size of the widget and the number of lines are independent. If you want to restrict the height, are you specifically asking about limting how many lines can be entered, or do you only really care about the physical height of the widget?

Comment: Only the physical height so that the forms on my GUI and labels all line up in a predictable way.
However, if you wanted to add an answer about restriction of number of characters as well I would mark it helpful as it would likely be of use to those finding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [text widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) instead.  It has a height option

Note: place requires integers that represent pixels, however, within the options of the text box, the width option requires integers that represent number of characters, and the height option requires an integer that represents number of lines.  If you attempt to use height=20 expecting 20 pixels, you will be unpleasantly surprised.  If you use width = 5, height = 5 it will not be square.

For reference, the default text size and font is an average of 8 pixels wide per character in the text widget, and 6 pixels per character in the default for the entry widget, so if you wanted a form to stretch a certain number of pixels, use width = round(pixel_length /6)

you can combine this with screen width and placement of the corner of forms to fill across the page or to near the end if you like

Comment: Your comment is a bit hard to understand. When you say _"width requires integers that represent the number of characters'_, that's only partly true. You're using `place`, and `place` has a width option that uses pixels. It is the `width` option of the `Text` widget that is in the number of characters.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley I've edited it to be more clear